# Bootstrap 3 move left column to right in responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to somehow get a column in bootstrap that is on the left to be on the right only when it's tablet or phone?
(read; on the bottom, or after the right column)

Desktop view:

```
___________________________
|Menu 1  | the-main-column |
|Menu 2  |                 |
---------------------------
```

tablet/phone view:

```
_________________
| menu 1         |
------------------
| the-main-column|
------------------
| menu 2         |
------------------
```

I have it set up like this:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="menuone"></div>
      <div class="menutwo"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But that obviously won't work

Answer (score 4):

<s>Yes, you can use `.col-md-push-8` on your left column to push your leftbar to the right.</s>

Also, you can use `.col-md-pull-4` on your main content.

Thank you Evan for the reminder for me to post a code demo, I have a new understanding to the question today by reading the updated question.

Below is the solution:

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  #content-container {
    position:relative;
  }
  #main {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:15px;
  }
  #menu-2 {
    float:none;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="content-container">
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="menu-1">
    Menu 1
    <p>Try viewing in full page.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8" id="main">
    Main
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam feugiat pharetra nisl, vitae dapibus est imperdiet eu. Suspendisse id eros ligula. Maecenas eu massa ut quam consequat vulputate. Maecenas sed dui nisl. Quisque volutpat eleifend pellentesque. Praesent auctor bibendum sapien, eget mollis ligula molestie nec. Quisque aliquam lectus sit amet ante hendrerit vehicula. Fusce quis feugiat nunc. Suspendisse quis condimentum metus. Praesent sit amet ligula ex. Praesent viverra sit amet urna eu semper. Suspendisse venenatis varius maximus. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="menu-2">Menu 2</div>
</div>
```

The solution uses extra CSS to work. The CSS should be simple enough to understand. But you can comment to let me know to further explain. :)

Comment: @EvanSiroky Thank you for reminding me. I've updated my answer :)